# If a reviewer comments that the overall writing needs to be improved will they reject if some errors remain?

Tags: publications, phd, research-process, citations, peer-review

I submitted the major revision and one reviewer's comment was to improve the overall writing. I'm trying to improve the flow and writing, but some grammatical errors and typos are still left.

Will they reject it directly or give me another chance?

Comment: Are you talking about a paper submission to a journal? If so, keep in mind that it is the editor who will reject or 'give you another chance', not the reviewers. They are merely experts you are helping the editor to make the best choices.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84690/marking-a-journal-paper-as-minor-revisions-needed-for-minor-typos

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17111/what-suggestions-should-i-make-when-reviewing-a-poorly-written-paper

Comment: I think it will depend on the severity of the remaining issues. A few typos might be acceptable, a manuscript ridden with typos not.

Answer (score 8):

First:  If you know your paper has grammatical or spelling errors, you must fix them before you submit the paper.  Otherwise, you risk wasting the editor and peer reviewers' time, which would be unethical.  Remember they are volunteers with other responsibilities.

If you did submit a paper that was perfect except for spelling and minor grammar errors, it usually would not be rejected.  Most journals make their decisions based on research content, not cosmetics.  Most journals employ a copyeditor to fix cosmetic errors the authors cannot fix.

Answer (score 1):

If you *know* these grammatical errors & typos exist, you should fix them before resubmitting. Submitting something with known flaws just waste other's time and effort.

That said, if you receive a review comment asking you to improve the writing, it often means that the writing is pretty bad, so you will need substantial corrections. If you make these substantial corrections then the reviewer will probably not be angry, since you did after all attempt to fix the issue. Maybe the fix isn't perfect, but at least you tried.

Reviewers can and often do get annoyed if you make only superficial attempts to incorporate their suggestions. That is when you might get a "reject" review.